# Is possible to covert to postgresql with regex or other method?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, postgresql

Now, I have some results from JSON parse to SQL, and where clause is different with postgresql.
Then, need to convert with regex or replace it, but I am not familiar with regex.

```
SELECT Column_name, Column_name_2, Column_name_3 FROM sample WHERE LIKE(Column_name_2, "text") OR LIKE(Column_name_2, "text_2") OR LIKE(Column_name_2, "text_3") OR LIKE(Column_3, cwcwsd) LIMIT 100;
```

Output:

```
SELECT Column_name, Column_name_2, Column_name_3 FROM sample WHERE Column_name_2 LIKE "text" OR Column_name_2 LIKE "text_2" OR Column_name_2 LIKE "text_3" OR Column_name_2 LIKE cwcwsd LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach is to create a PostgreSQL function LIKE(text, text):

```
create or replace function LIKE(text, text)
returns boolean
language sql
AS $$
  SELECT $1 LIKE $2;
$$;
```

Test it:

```
SELECT LIKE('success', 'su%');
```

Returns true;